# How to get email address of CC

Tags: gmail

I recently received a mail which contained a CC. I want to reply to the person who wrote to me however I want to CC the person he had already CC'd but I don't know his mail. Can I somehow get the CC'd person's email address?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on '**View Details**', you will able to see From, To and CC addresses.

To respond everyone in that email, just click on 'Reply all' instead of 'Reply'.